# Blank Screen when running Asp.net mvc 5 web app on Mac Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, macos, visual-studio

When I run the ASP.NET MVC web app on my mac from Visual Studio, it opens up in the browser (Chrome), but the screen is blank. I can go to any link on that port and it will show me a blank screen. But when I stop the project from the IDE, chrome will tell me that localhost refused/failed to connect.

1. OS: Mac Os
2. IDE: Visual Studio 2017

It was working perfectly yesterday. :/

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem. I Tried various other solutions, none worked. I then deleted the whole project and clone from its remote repo again, and the problem was no longer there.